# Regex capture group works in regex101, not sed

Tags: sed, grep

I found some other similarly titled questions but didn't find the answer.

My text is:

```
##bcftools_mergeCommand=merge --force-samples -m none -O v -o analysis/STUDY1/hg19/exome/merged.vcf --threads 4 analysis/STUDY1/hg19/exome/varscan_norm.vcf.gz analysis/STUDY1/hg19/exome/gatk_norm.vcf.gz analysis/STUDY1/hg19/exome/samtools_norm.vcf.gz analysis/STUDY1/hg19/exome/freebayes_norm.vcf.gz
```

I want the names of the .vcf.gz files.

Sed gives me:

```
echo "##bcftools_mergeCommand=merge --force-samples -m none -O v -o analysis/STUDY1/hg19/exome/merged.vcf --threads 4 analysis/STUDY1/hg19/exome/varscan_norm.vcf.gz analysis/STUDY1/hg19/exome/gatk_norm.vcf.gz analysis/STUDY1/hg19/exome/samtools_norm.vcf.gz analysis/STUDY1/hg19/exome/freebayes_norm.vcf.gz" | sed -En 's/\/([^\/]+\.vcf\.gz)/\1/g'
```

with blank results.

Regex101 gives:

[image]

https://regex101.com/r/h3OGvN/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not using grep ?

```
$ data='##bcftools_mergeCommand=merge --force-samples -m none -O v -o analysis/STUDY1/hg19/exome/merged.vcf --threads 4 analysis/STUDY1/hg19/exome/varscan_norm.vcf.gz analysis/STUDY1/hg19/exome/gatk_norm.vcf.gz analysis/STUDY1/hg19/exome/samtools_norm.vcf.gz analysis/STUDY1/hg19/exome/freebayes_norm.vcf.gz'
$ echo $data | grep -Eo [^\/]+\.vcf\.gz
varscan_norm.vcf.gz
gatk_norm.vcf.gz
samtools_norm.vcf.gz
freebayes_norm.vcf.gz
```

---

- `-E`: Interpret patterns as extended regular expressions.
- `-o`: Print only the matched (non-empty) parts.

Comment: Great job! I thought had tried that, but must have not had it quite right.

Comment: You don't need to escape `/` in a regexp, it's already literal. You do need to quote variables and strings in any shell command though and if you use `*` instead of `+` then you can use greps default BRE instead of enabling EREs - `echo "$data" | grep -o '[^/]*\.vcf\.gz'`.

Answer (score 0):

The regex dialect supported by Regex101 is different from the one `sed` understands.

Concretely, (take out the superflous `g` flag and) add a `p` flag to print the matching lines to fix this specific script; but in the general case, don't rely on a tool which doesn't directly support the one you actually want to use.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 'y/ \//\n\n/;/\`\S+\.vcf\.gz$/MP;D' file
```

Match spaces and `/` to newlines and use the `P;D` idiom to print/delete a match of the first line in the result